# How to receive a type of each Record member in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I google the answer but still haven't found it.
So, I have to post it here.

The problem is pretty simple:

Let's say I have a Record of any Abstract class.

```
const record = Record<string, Model>
```

And I also have several implementations of my model:

```
class A extends Model {
  foo() {
    return 'foo';
  }
}

class B extends Model {
  bar() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

and then I store my models in my record:

```
record.classA = new A();
record.classB = new B();
```

As we can see, properties in my record are dynamic.

So, the question is: Is that possible to get a type of each key and all of the keys of my model?

For example, I want to have something like this:

```
function get(key: string) {
  return record[key]; //Here I expect to receive a correct type (for example class A or class B regarding the key)
}
```

And another question is that possible to get all existing keys when I hit enter after "record."?

I read about function overloading but could be another solution or can I dynamically overload my functions? I want to create a module structure for my app.

Thanks a lot!

Regards, Dmitry

Comment: You can only do this if you are willing to initialize your `record` all in one go with an object literal

Comment: Not really clear what do you mean by "get type", but if you can just initialize the object with known keys - typescript will infer the types on its own https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiaBvAsAKGn6AtkqtALzQDkBFA3DgL446iQwCC0yAHgC7IB2iGAhRosuaADN48ABQBKDDnzQATsh4BXVf0rT4tZdEbYTzcFGgAhTrwFC4xMUYBGYVQqUS86rTspuqoYSJmbYwPD8EDxqyBGqiGReKixQbABc0PzIAO7QbAoANEZ4qRBWmdl5VkUMTNg8AJ4ADsjQAEpx8AkAGklNrfCSsfGINNBAA

Comment: (`const record = Record<string, Model>` I assume is supposed to be `const record: Record<string, Model> = {};`)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is a staticaly-typed language. That means that if you define `record` as `Record<string, Model>`. All of its keys will always be of type `Model`.

If you want to have a more complex type. You should define it either using generic or ahead of time.

```
const record = {
  classA: new A(),
  classB: new B(),
}
```

Generic would require a wrapper

```
class RecoldHolder<T extends Record<string, Model>> {
  record: T;

  get<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
    return this.record[key];
  }
}
```

---

PS: Do not ever use keywords as function names, you will encounter really strange behaviours at times. Use `getter`, instead of `get`, etc.